# Adding Woo Commerce tax filter

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i'm trying to add a filter to woo commerce, that calculate tax based on amount of cart and only when items are shipped to new york, Orders > 110$ not paying taxes, and orders < 110$ & shipping to new york state should pay 8,865% tax.
I found this code somewhere but not sure if works, neither where to use it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class','big_apple_get_tax_class', 1, 2 );

function big_apple_get_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {
if ( WC()->cart->subtotal <= 110 )
    $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

return $tax_class;
}
```

Apreciatte any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Added the contion for Tax below/above the 110
        $this->total = max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', round( $this->cart_contents_total +  $this->fee_total, $this->dp ), $this ) );

        if($this->total > 110){
            $this->total = max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', round( $this->cart_contents_total + $this->tax_total + $this->shipping_tax_total + $this->shipping_total + $this->fee_total, $this->dp ), $this ) );
        }else{
            $this->taxes  = 0;
        }
```

Added in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php

Comment: You shouldn't touch plugin files as much as you can.